Is there a shorthand to go forward through children in git? (opposite of ~)
I have a completely linear git history (to make things simple), such that
git log --oneline --graph --all
shows
* eff3139 (branch_2) foo
* f217e05 bar
* 8d1c27b baz
* c10bb66 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) qux
* dd2952b quz
* 321dedc zot
* b00284b blarg

with head sitting on master at c10bb66, it's easy for me to check out dd2952b with git checkout @~ or 321dedc using the same but with @~2. However, how do I easily checkout 8d1c27b, or f217e05, or other children of the current commit?
git checkout @~-1 (my only idea) unfortunately leads to the error error: pathspec '@~-1' did not match any file(s) known to git
I suspect there's no way to do this in git, which is a shame.

Git doesn't provide a built-in shorthand for referencing child commits, I've upvoted anyway to see if someone has a cool hack around for it. :-)

If you're willing to add a script as an alias, it seems history is replete with many cool hacks to choose from! Some of them probably better or worse.

@eftshift0 Children point to parents. :-)

Oh! Hahaha let me remove that. That was a lapsus

I suspect there is no way to do this in git, unless there has been some recent addition. Although the question asked isn't exactly the same, the answers to What is the opposite of `git diff HEAD^`?, Referencing the child of a commit in Git, and How do I find the next commit in Git? (child/children of ref) seem to suggest that there is no way to do this in git.
(Many of the answers erroneously suggest that this is impossible as a matter of principle — but it's not impossible, as git log --oneline --graph --all shows; git just won't let you do it.)

"(Many of the answers erroneously suggest that this is impossible as a matter of principle — but it's not impossible, as git log --oneline --graph --all shows; git just won't let you do it.)" - That version of the command shows also the child commits of the commit pointed by HEAD, because --all implies every ref as supplied, i.e. every head commit of every branch. According to --all docs: "Pretend as if all the refs in refs/, along with HEAD, are listed on the command line as ." You're comparing two very different versions of the command.

I wonder why you think people think erroneously that it's not possible. Sure.... You can read all commit objects in a repo, check all their parents and find which of those commits have a given commit as their parent and therefore find a list of all the children of a given commit but you can't just check a commit object and finds its children from it the same way you can find its parents (which are specified in the commit object itself).

Yes, that's why.

The desired operation is finding a child commit of the current commit, which is possible (using the method you've described). The desired operation is not the commit object having a reference to its children — in which case that really would be impossible in git! I think people like to bring up the latter to explain why git won't let you do the former (because it's computationally expensive), but some of them stray too far and suggest that it can't be done at all.
